# Image file encoding not applicable

Tags: python, python-requests

I want to download images from the web to my python project file. I set the file type as write bytes to write the bytes into another file using default UTF-8 encoding.

The download is successful but it is labelled as a text file not a image.

When I try opening the txt file it gives me a message."The document “NVALU.txt” could not be opened. Text encoding Unicode (UTF-8) isn’t applicable. The file may have been saved using a different text encoding, or it may not be a text file."

I've tried changing the encoding format as other peoples say but my IDE recommends me not to saying that the format is incompatible and does not support the text.

There is a drop down menu for all the formats but the all have warning symbols next to them(red exclamations)
or they have yellow exclamations, not one of them doesn't have.

```
#this module makes random files and allows you to write in them

import random
import requests

print('To create a random file run function (make_file)')

def make_file():

    picture = requests.get('https://news.nationalgeographic.com/content/dam/news/2018/05/17/you-can-train-your-cat/02-cat-training-NationalGeographic_1484324.ngsversion.1526587209178.adapt.1900.1.jpg')   #Finds the picture using that URL

    emp = []
    alpha2 = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    count = 0
    while count <= 4:
        count = count +1
        emp.append(random.choice(alpha2))
    new_emp = ''.join(emp)+'.txt'
    ##################.  problem below
    with open(new_emp , 'wb') as f:
        f.write(picture.content)
        print('File {} created !'.format(new_emp))

make_file()
```

I expected for the image to be successfully written to my python project folder where I normally download the images. Which allows me to open them without a problem.

Comment: This isn't a Python related question, your image is saved properly from the Python side and it can be opened and seen in any image viewer or editor. Your problem that  you have got with the OS would have been solved if you had appended `.jpg` instead `.txt` to that random name.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simply that you're writing an image (specifically a jpg) into a file with a .txt extension. At minimum all you need to do is swap this line

```py
new_emp = ''.join(emp)+'.txt'
```

with this

```py
new_emp = ''.join(emp)+'.jpg'
```

However a more nuanced approach that automatically finds what the extension of the web file is from the URL string may be better in future.

Your OS freaked out when you tried to open your new .txt file because the data inside is anything but some standard text. Notepad on Windows will open them though it just produces garbage text. Other OSs/software appear to be less lenient and refuse to open it at all. It's just a case of mistaken identity.

I personally prefer using urllib for downloads as it has all the `with open` faff done for you though it's down to use case and personal taste:

```py
import urllib
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://website.org/image.jpg", "localfilename.jpg")
```